# Qt deploying issue on other computer

Tags: c++, qt, deployment

I have a deployment problem after having compiled the release of my program. I can use it on my computer, but it doesn't work on another computer unless I install Qt on it.

I tried to compile with `MSVC2012` and `MinGW`:

With `MSVC2012`, the program doesn't show any error messages.

With `MinGW` the program sends me a c++ runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

1. Compile Qt with static libraries and link you program with those static libraries. All dependencies will be included in the program binary.
2. Ship Qt dynamic libraries that your program needs with your program.
3. Ask the user to install Qt libraries with the same major version you used to compile your program.

I'm not a Windows guys so I can't tell you Windows specifics, but these will do the job.

Comment: Qt is too heavy for each user can install it. What do you advise me? QT with static libraries or Qt dynamic libraries ?

Comment: Qt dynamic libraries is usually the best way to go - especially if you are using the LGPL license.